# counting unique visitors with flask

Tags: flask

I would like to count the number of unique visitors and store that number in my database. I know that I can get the ip address with

```
request.remote_addr
```

so my default plan would be to store this address with a timestamp in my database. For any new visitor I would than compare whether this ip address has already been added with a timestamp less than 1 day old.
This would give me the number of visitors per day.

However, I have the feeling this is a problem where others probably came up with better solutions already? Any suggestion how to do this better?

p.s. I just need a rough estimate for the number of unique visits, so the fact that ip addresses are not a good measure is not that concerning to me... but if you have better suggestions I am definitely interested

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get a faster more reliable solution, simply offload this functionality to another service like [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/). They provide a very detailed/in-depth view of the traffic on your website without you having to worry about the intricate details.

Regardless, if you're dead set on using flask, take a look at [this](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/saturday-morning-hacks-building-an-analytics-app-with-flask/) wonderful blog post explaining how to build an analytics app in Flask. [Here](https://gist.github.com/coleifer/9899de010c647823a14f) is the complete source code of that app.

Comment: google analytics seems like a nice solution... thanks a lot for the tip

Comment: @oxlorg: Does google analytics provide api so we can retrieve the data for storing in our db ?